# Width of nav caused page extra space to the right

Tags: html, css, nav

I have a problem with my nav where it's so wide that it keep giving me extra space to the right. I have no idea why it's so wide, I tried making the with of it smaller with some code, but I'm making the site responsive and when I bring the code down to around 320px it is based on the screen size making the words really hard to see and click. Actually it looks fine on my local computer when I test it, but putting it on a server and actually looking at it on my phone makes it look terrible. Anyone have any problems like this before or can maybe see what I'm doing wrong? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cajE8/)

HTML5

```
<div id="header-banner">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>    <a href="index.html">
            <img id="logo" alt="PT Logo" src="Images/PT-logo.png"></a>

            <nav id="main-nav">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">CityName</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">CityName</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS3

```
/* ===== HEADER NAVIGATION AREA ===== */
 #main-nav {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#nav {
    list-style: none;
    margin: auto;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
#nav li a {
    color: #DB7093;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 15px;
    height: 20px;
}
#nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #DB7093;
    color: #F0F8FF;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the `margin:auto`, and edit `padding: 3px 15px` to `padding: 3px 1px`, just to see whether this is your porblem.

This might be the solution:

```
 

     #main-nav {
        position: relative;
        left: 50%;
        width:350px;
        bottom: 20px;
        height: 40px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

Add `width`property to your `#main-nav`.

Comment: removing the margin just caused it to fall down and making it a padding of 3px 1px makes all the words just fall closer together, there is 15px on each side of the word. It doesn't change the width at all.

Comment: Ah, dude(t) I'm such a moron, I don't know what I didn't think up something so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8K2bL/

```
/* MOBILE - 649 = logo + nav */
@media only screen and (max-width: 649px) {
#logo{display:block !important;}
#main-nav{
    margin:0 auto !important;
    bottom:auto !important;
    right:auto !important;
}
header{
    width:320px !important;
    margin:0 auto;
}
}

#logo{
width:auto;
height:100%;
display:inline;
}
header{
height:100px;
width:100%;
position:relative;
}

/* ===== HEADER NAVIGATION AREA ===== */
 #main-nav {
float:right;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try structuring the html better. I updated your js fiddle and restructured the html, added a couple of classes and modified the existing `#main-nav`. You can find it in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cajE8/1/)

I would also recommend you to look in to [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) for responsive css layouts

Comment: @SecretWalrus If you are looking at responsive design don't use fixed `px` width. You'll face issues when your page is opened in different resolution screens. In mozilla browser you have Tools->Web Developer->Responsive design view. Check your page in different resolutions!